# Facebook multi-friend-selector for iframe application?

Tags: php, facebook, iframe

I would like to add facebook multi-friend-selector in my facebook iframe appplication that using PHP.

Can i add it to my application? on anyway?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector)

If the link is down then go to http://fbrell.com/examples and select `xfbml — fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector` from the list.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is down.

Answer (score 0):

These pages might help:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector_%28condensed%29

Answer (score 0):

Here is the FBML to create the multi-friend-selector and the javascript to render the XFBML (the FB JS SDK automatically parses/renders fbml elements)...

```
<fb:serverfbml>
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:request-form action="http://yourdomain.com" method="get" invite="true" type="MyPeeps Mahjong" content="Checkout my app <fb:req-choice url='http://apps.facebook.com/myapp to app'> ">
<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="true"
actiontext="Invite your friends to play this game"
rows="5" cols="5" bypass="cancel"  />
</fb:request-form>
</script>
</fb:serverfbml>

<script type="text/javascript">

FB.init('API_KEY', receiver);

FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil","Connect","XFBML"], function()
{
    FB.XdComm.Server.init("xd_receiver.htm");
});

FB.ensureInit(function()
{
    FB.XFBML.Host.get_areElementsReady().waitUntilReady(function()
    {
    });
});

</script>
```